Too Much Gap Between Roof Decking?
Should there be gaps between decking, on a new roof? City inspectors passed the job but they didn't actually come to the site. Apparently they pass inspections based on photos provided by the roofers themselves. Meanwhile, my indpendent inspector says its a problem. I'm not sure what to do now. I don't want to run into problems when I sell the house, 3 years from now. Is my independent inspector being unreasonable? Is this something I should ask the roofers to fix? If so, do they need to take it apart fromt he top, to do so? Or can the problem be resolved from inside the attic? TIA! 

Is this a brand new roof including the sheeting? That doesn’t look like new material. If it was installed decades ago the code has most likely changed since then. That being said, it looks like a pretty shoddy job but shouldn’t cause any serious problems. Keep in mind, private inspectors are paid to find every little thing they can to give you your money’s worth.

Thank you for responding. Good point. They did replace most of the sheeting but I think you're right and should have noticed that this particular issue (there are a few) was related to the existing sheeting and, as such, is definitly my problem. Again. Thank you!

Did they use used plywood on the roof, or did they replace only parts of the plywood? That certainly does not look like new plywood.

There are supposed to be expansion gaps between sheets of plywood on a roof. I can't tell from these pictures whether those are the right size (3mm or 1/8 inch) or too large, but the sheets should NOT be butted hard up to each other (Simpson (and, I suppose, probably others) even sells clips which help maintain the right spacing, and transfer loading between sheets in between rafters/trusses.)

A 1/8-inch space between adjacent panel end and edge joints is recommended, unless panel manufacturer indicates otherwise. Check building code requirements for installation of panel edge clips. Edge clip requirements depend on the relationship of the panel Span Rating to the actual distance between roof framing.

Quote from https://www.apawood.org/buildertips/pages/N335.html

If you are worried about leaks, the gaps aren't really in the equation.    If you are worried about running around on the roof, then maybe too big.
